# Probability of taking out coins by order

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification

> The question goes as following:
>   There is a jar with 65 coins. 30 are green, 15 are yellow and 20 are red.
>   When taking out 20 coins from the jar, one by one, what is the probability that the first three coins and last three coins selected will be green?

My logic was that if I only look at the first 3 and last 3 selected, there are $30 \cdot 29\cdot 28\cdot 27\cdot 26\cdot 25$ options for them to be green, and a total of $65\cdot 64\cdot 63\cdot 62\cdot 61\cdot 60$ options to choose the first and last 3.
So the probability should be $ (30 \cdot 29\cdot 28\cdot 27\cdot 26\cdot 25)\div (65\cdot 64\cdot 63\cdot 62\cdot 61\cdot 60) $

Would appreciate any comments regarding if this answer makes sense or not.

Comment: The answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see for $7$ balls:
$$P(\color{green}{G_1G_2G_3}(\color{green}G \text{ or } G')_4\color{green}{G_5G_6G_7})=\\
P(\color{green}{G_1G_2G_3G_4G_5G_6G_7})+P(\color{green}{G_1G_2G_3}G'_4\color{green}{G_5G_6G_7})=\\
\color{green}{\frac{30}{65}\cdot \frac{29}{64}\cdot \frac{28}{63}}\cdot \color{green}{\frac{27}{62}\cdot \frac{26}{61}\cdot \frac{25}{60}\cdot \frac{24}{59}}+
\color{green}{\frac{30}{65}\cdot \frac{29}{64}\cdot \frac{28}{63}}\cdot \frac{35}{62}\cdot  \color{green}{\frac{27}{61}\cdot \frac{26}{60}\cdot \frac{25}{59}}=\\
\color{green}{\frac{30}{65}\cdot \frac{29}{64}\cdot \frac{28}{63}}\cdot \color{green}{\frac{27}{62}\cdot \frac{26}{61}\cdot \frac{25}{60}}\cdot \left(\frac{\color{green}{24}+35}{59}\right)=\\
\color{green}{\frac{30}{65}\cdot \frac{29}{64}\cdot \frac{28}{63}}\cdot \color{green}{\frac{27}{62}\cdot \frac{26}{61}\cdot \frac{25}{60}}$$

Similarly:
$$P(\color{green}{G_1G_2G_3}(\color{green}G \text{ or } G')_4...(\color{green}G \text{ or }G')_{17}\color{green}{G_{18}G_{19}G_{20}})=\\
\color{green}{\frac{30}{65}\cdot \frac{29}{64}\cdot \frac{28}{63}}\cdot \color{green}{\frac{27}{62}\cdot \frac{26}{61}\cdot \frac{25}{60}}.$$

Comment: This is wrong answer.

Comment: @kludg, because...

Comment: because draws from 4th to 17th could be anything including green

Comment: and what do you think $\frac{35}{62}$ is?

Comment: I don't know; I think it is wrong.

Comment: You have computed the probability that the first 3 draws are green, the middle 14 are not green, and the last 3 are green. This is not what was asked; you added in the extra condition that the middle 14 draws are not green.

Comment: well it's obvious that the fraction $27/48$ tells that you made the hypothesis that no green has been taken....except for the first three greens.

Comment: @kludg and MikeEarnest, thank you for clarifying, corrected.